# ModifyAsync Not Working

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm attempting to edit an embedded message after it is posted. I was attempting to use this example from the documentation but it just does not work. https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.MessageProperties.html

```
var message = await ReplyAsync("abc");
await message.ModifyAsync(x =>
{
    x.Content = "";
    x.Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .WithColor(new Color(40, 40, 120))
        .WithAuthor(a => a.Name = "foxbot")
        .WithTitle("Embed!")
        .WithDescription("This is an embed.");
});
```

Putting the code into one of my working commands will give a

> cannot implicitly convert type `Discord.EmbedBuilder` to `Discord.Optional<Discord.Embed>`"

Really confused...

Comment: You are missing a `.Build()` after `WithDescription`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `.Build()` after `WithDescription`. Usually when using the builder pattern you usually need to *build* the desired type.

```
var message = await ReplyAsync("abc");
await message.ModifyAsync(x =>
{
    x.Content = "";
    x.Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .WithColor(new Color(40, 40, 120))
        .WithAuthor(a => a.Name = "foxbot")
        .WithTitle("Embed!")
        .WithDescription("This is an embed.")
        .Build(); //<-- The is what was omitted.
});
```

Calling `Build()` would return a `Embed` which can then be implicitly converted to `Optional<Embed>"`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much.